# Get last 12 months data from Db with year in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to fetch last 12 months data from db, I have written a query for that but that only giving me count and month but not year means month related to which year.

My Sql :

```
Select count(B.id),date_part('month',revision_timestamp) from package AS
 A INNER JOIN  package_revision AS B ON A.revision_id=B.revision_id 
 WHERE  revision_timestamp > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months') 
GROUP BY  date_part('month',revision_timestamp)
```

it gives me output like this

```
 month | count 
-------+-------
     7 |     21
     8 |      4
     9 |     10
```

but I want year with month like  7 - 2012, or year in other col, doesn't matter

Comment: Include `date_part('year', revision_timestamp)` somewhere...?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you wanted this:

```
SELECT to_char(revision_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'),
       count(b.id)
FROM package a
JOIN package_revision b ON a.revision_id = b.revision_id
WHERE revision_timestamp >
      date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 year'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select
    count(B.id),
    date_part('year', revision_timestamp) as year,
    date_part('month',revision_timestamp) as month
from package as A
    inner join package_revision as B on A.revision_id=B.revision_id 
where
    revision_timestamp > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months') 
group by
    date_part('year', revision_timestamp)
    date_part('month', revision_timestamp)
```

or

```
select
    count(B.id),
    to_char(revision_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') as month
from package as A
    inner join package_revision as B on A.revision_id=B.revision_id 
where
    revision_timestamp > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months') 
group by
    to_char(revision_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Keep in mind that, if you filter by `revision_timestamp > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months')`, you'll get range from current date in last year (so if today is `'2013-09-04'` you'll get range from `'2012-09-04'`)