# Getting numbers from Last Year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have looked at posts regarding time element in postgreSQL but they have not thus far clicked for me. I want to get `Last Year to Date`, in this case 01/01/2016 to 03/20/2016 and `Last Year Month to Date`, in this case 03/01/2016 to 03/20/2016.

[Get last 12 months data from Db with year in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607110/get-last-12-months-data-from-db-with-year-in-postgres)

[get last three month records from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117582/get-last-three-month-records-from-table)

```
select actual_sale_date from allsalesdata
where actual_sale_date > date_trunc('year', current_date)
```

provides with Year to Date for 2017

```
select actual_sale_date from allsalesdata
where actual_sale_date > date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

provides with Month to Date for 2017

```
select actual_sale_date from allsalesdata
where actual_sale_date >= date_trunc('year', now() - interval '1 year')         
and actual_sale_date < date_trunc('year',now())
```

provides with Last Year from 01/01 ----> 12/31 Data.

What can I add to the above snippets which would provide me with Last Year to Date and Last Year Month to Date data. Please provide assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
select actual_sale_date 
from allsalesdata
where actual_sale_date + interval '1' year >= date_trunc('year', current_date) and
      actual_sale_date + interval '1' year < current_date
```

That is, add a year to last year's date and compare to this year.  I recommend adding one year and using *this* year's date.  That handles leap years more intuitively (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

Your formulas are hard to follow. You need to construct the query combining actual_sale_date against one and another date. so:

start of previous year:

```
t=# select date_trunc('year', now() - interval '1 year');
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2016-01-01 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

start of current day:

```
t=# select date_trunc('day', now());
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2017-03-20 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

start of current month in previous year:

```
t=# select date_trunc('month', (now() - interval '1 year'));
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2016-03-01 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

So if "Last Year Month to Date data" means from 2016, March the first till now:

```
select actual_sale_date from allsalesdata
where actual_sale_date >= date_trunc('month', (now() - interval '1 year'))       
and actual_sale_date <= now()
```